# Plot unique items using rows and columns - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting various arrows grouped by a unique items in a column. Using below, the unique items are recorded in `Label`. The function works fine if the subplots contain a single row or column. However, when aiming to incorporate multiple rows/columns, I'm returning an error (see below).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns

def plot(dfs, label):

    # works fine if all subplots are initialised using single row or column 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,8,figsize=(12,6))
    fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.025, bottom = 0.05, right = 0.98, top = 0.95, wspace = 0.2, hspace = 0.3)   

    for ind,l in enumerate(label):
    
        df = dfs[dfs['Label'] == l]
    
        unq_labels = label
        col_values = sns.color_palette('Set2')
        color_map = dict(zip(unq_labels, col_values))
        colors = [color_map[label] for label in df['Label'].values]
            
        X = df['X'] 
        Y = df['Y'] 
        U = df['U'] 
        V = df['V'] 
    
        ax[ind].quiver(X, Y, (U-X), (V-Y), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, color = colors)
        ax[ind].set_title('class %s' % l)
    
    plt.show()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('XYUV'))
labels = df['X'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'])) 
df['Label'] = labels
unq = df['Label'].unique()
    
plot(df, unq)
```

So, if I alter the following line to display multiple rows and columns:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4,figsize=(12,6))
```

The following error gets returned:

```
ax[ind].quiver(X, Y, (U-X), (V-Y), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, color = colors)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'quiver'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have several rows/columns, `subplots()` returns a 2D NumPy array of Axes, which you need to access using `ax[i,j]`.

Another option is to iterate over a flattened view of the array:

```py
for l,ax in zip(label, ax.flat):
    (...)
    ax.quiver(X, Y, (U-X), (V-Y), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, color = colors)
    ax.set_title('class %s' % l)
    (...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I initially thought the numpy type was the cause of the error.